# How to reset product id using In-App purchases?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have two apps in my **iTunesConnect** account, both of them use In-App purchases. For both of them I need to create product with apriopriate product identifiers. For first app I created a product with apriopriate identifier, but that product should be in a second app.

So **I removed** that product from the first app, and then I tried to create the same one for the second one, but then error arised:

> The product ID you entered has already been used. Enter a unique product ID and try again.

[image]

I really need the same product identifier in my second app. How can I reset or make it able to recreate for a different app?

Answer (score 5):

Simply, it is impossible> Direct answer from Apple:

> "After you submit your product ID, you cannot edit it or reuse it for another In-App Purchase. **We are not able** to reset the In-App Purchase product IDs for your account."

Comment: Can I create new app in itunes connect to reuse the productid?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk if i want to edit, can i delete old product id and create new?

Comment: No, you cannot.